# R: count number of different values of 2 factor vectors

Tags: r

I have two vectors with the same length -- both are factors. I want to compare them position by position to see how many of are different. For example

```
> a = as.factor(c(1,2,2,1,2,2,1))
> b = as.factor(c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1))
```

Since there are two different values at position 3 and position 5, I'd like to get 2 as the final results. I know I can convert them to numeric numbers and do a subtraction, but what if the value are strings, e.g.

```
a = as.factor(c("a","a","b"))
b = as.factor(c("a","b","b"))
```

Are there any elegant, general ways to do this?

Comment: I'd go with `table(a==b)`

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a general solution you have to ensure that both factors have the same levels:

```
ab_levels <- unique(c(levels(a), levels(b)))
```

After that you can simply sum:

```
sum(factor(a, ab_levels) == factor(b, ab_levels))
```

Without adjusting levels both `table` + `==` and `sum` will fail on something like this:

```
> a <- as.factor(c("a","a","c"))
> b <- as.factor(c("a","b","b"))
> table(a == b)
Error in Ops.factor(a, b) : level sets of factors are different
```

Another approach is to use `table` without `==`:

```
> tbl <- table(a, b)
> sum(tbl) - sum(diag(tbl))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's [@Frank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191601/r-count-number-of-different-values-of-2-factor-vectors/32191703#comment52268424_32191601):

> I'd go with `table(a==b)`